# Laravel relationship and get data of third table

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have three tables:

**payment**: (payment_id, Fee_id)

**Fees**: (Fee_id, Term_id)

**Term**: (Term_id, Term_name)

From the above table I need to make relationship. Then I need orm method to get data of term table values from using a payment model.
How to make this

Comment: please show us your models

Comment: I not created model relationship. Please can u creat and show me model. I have three models

Comment: Have you created the models though? Since you're not following Laravel's standard practice for table or column names you'll have to have set up the models accordingly.

Comment: I just need laravel orm query get data first table and third table

Comment: Yeah, I get that. However, Stackoverflow isn't a place to come and get other people to write your code for you, you have to do at least some of the work. So again, have you at least created the models and set them up, not added the relationships, just set them up?

Comment: I have created relationship already but I cannot access my code now.i show my model tommorow

Comment: Ok. The relationships you want are `Payment` belongsTo `Fee`, `Fee` belongsto `Term`, and then you would just need `$payment->fee->term;` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: I need to write in  query with()

Comment: I request data from ajax